# Copy files from host to docker container using docker API

Tags: docker, docker-api

Anybody know about, How to copy files from host machine to docker container using docker API?

or Anyone knows,
How to use this API? -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/PutContainerArchive
In which format I have to upload the files using this API?

Comment: The Docker API link you sent says "tar archive" in a couple of places.  Do you _need_ to send files to a container's temporary file system?  Can you use a Docker SDK, instead of directly talking to the HTTP API?  Do you have any existing code you can share?

Comment: @DavidMaze is there any official SDK for java from Docker?

Comment: [Develop with Docker Engine SDKs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) includes the two official SDKs (in Go and Python) and also links to community ones in many languages.